# When using spark-hbase, I got a ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.SparkSQLPushDownFilter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

Thanks for your help!

When I try to read from Hbase, I got Exception!

I'm try to set --jars and set spark.sparkContext.addJar("./hbase-spark-1.0.0.jar"),but it doesn't work;

And I also I try to keep hbase and sbt as the same version, it's doesn't work too;

my sbt code:

```
      "org.apache.hbase.connectors.spark" % "hbase-spark" % "1.0.0",
      "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "2.1.0" pomOnly(),
      "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "2.1.0"
```

my scala code:

```
val df = sql.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
    .option("hbase.columns.mapping",
      "name STRING :key, " +
        "email STRING c:email, " +
        "birthDate STRING p:birthDate, " +
        "height FLOAT p:height"
    )
    .option("hbase.table", "person")
    .load()
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("personView")

  val results = sql.sql("SELECT * FROM personView WHERE name = 'alice'")
  results.show()
```

my exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.SparkSQLPushDownFilter
```

my spark-submit:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--driver-memory 3G \
--class cn.run.HbaseTest \
--num-executors 2 \
--executor-memory 3G \
--executor-cores 2 \
--conf spark.ui.port=4399 \
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 \
--jars ./hbase-spark-1.0.0.jar \
SparkFM_2.11-2.4.3.jar \
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HBase Spark connector uses server-side filters and thus requires that you add several JAR files to the class path of each HBase region server:

- `hbase-spark-<connector.version>.jar`
- `hbase-spark-protocol-shaded-<connector.version>.jar`
- `scala-library-<scala.version>.jar`

Here, `<connector.version>` is the version of the HBase Spark connector, which in your case is `1.0.0`. `<scala.version>` is the version of the Scala run-time library, which in your case is `2.11.something`. You can pull the library from the local Maven cache. Look under

```
$HOME/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/<scala.version>/
```

In my HBase deployments, I usually create a `site-lib` directory in `$HBASE_HOME` and put the three files there, then set `HBASE_CLASSPATH` in `$HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-env.sh`. For example, using the snapshot version of the connector compiled for Spark 3.x:

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/site-lib/hbase-spark-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:$HBASE_HOME/site-lib/hbase-spark-protocol-shaded-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:$HBASE_HOME/site-lib/scala-library-2.12.12.jar
```

You still need to add the two JAR files (`hbase-spark` and `hbase-spark-protocol-shaded`) to your `spark-submit` command (or build a fat JAR) for the client-side components to work.

---

Another solution is to switch off filter pushdown by setting the `hbase.spark.pushdown.columnfilter` option to `false`:

```scala
val df = sql.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
    .option("hbase.columns.mapping", "...")
    .option("hbase.spark.pushdown.columnfilter", false)
    .option("hbase.table", "person")
    .load()
```

Note that this will prevent column filter operations such as `.filter("height > 1.0")` from running on the region servers and may result in unnecessary data transfers, therefore is not recommended unless you have no control over the HBase deployment.